# Discord.py voice stopping randomly

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am trying to code up a discord bot with some voice commands. One of them works normally:

```
async def padoru(ctx):
    if not bot.is_voice_connected(ctx.message.server):
        vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    else:
        await vc.move_to(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('padoru.mp3',after=lambda:print("padoru started"))
    player.start()
    while not player.is_done():
        pass
    await vc.disconnect()
```

While the other crashes the bot(after playing the song for a while):

```
async def kazoo(ctx):
    if not bot.is_voice_connected(ctx.message.server):
        vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    else:

        await vc.move_to(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player(random.choice(kazoos),after=lambda:print("kazoo started"))
    player.start()
    while not player.is_done():
        pass
    await vc.disconnect()
```

The crash doesn't really print anything, the bot just stops responding to any commands as well as stopping the voice command itself.

Comment: Instead of `pass`ing inside your waiting loop, `await asyncio.sleep(1)`.  This prevents your code from blocking the event loop.

Comment: That still has the same problem. I _think_ it might be because the song is too long(3 minutes), but I am not sure.